# Does MySQL obtains a lock on the table while adding a new composite index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table on production which is causing performance issues. I've identified a few quick indexes I can add to resolve the issue. Does MySQL obtains a lock on the table while adding a new index? Does it depend on the nature of index (unique, composite etc)?

Note that I don't have any specific need to add a new column so won't be running any `ALTER` command.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  _It matters._

Comment: MYSql Version: 5.7

Answer (score 0):

A `UNIQUE` index must check for uniqueness.

Any change to the `PRIMARY KEY` requires rebuilding the index.  (For InnoDB)

New versions of MySQL can add an index with very little impact.

Composite does not matter.

Adding a "new column" is a different question.  This, also, "depends".  New versions can do such "instantly" if you don't have the "after" clause.

Comment: My concern is regarding the locks. Does MySQL obtains any kind of lock (read/write) on the table while adding the index?